# Setting anchor properties depending on size of Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a windows form application that I have set all controls anchor properties to None so that when the form GROWS in size, the controls reposition themselves throughout the form in the same manner as they were before.

My issue is, with no anchoring, anytime the form shrinks below the width and/or height of the original form, the controls begin to disappear to the left and top of form itself. Even with AutoScroll = True for the form, no scroll bar appears and those controls are "lost" to the forms horizon until you have the form grow again.

Is there a method to set the anchor properties of the controls so that they anchor to top when form gets below a certain height and to left when the form gets below a certain width WHILE the user is resizing the form? I would also use a similar method to set the anchor properties back to None once the form grew above those values.

Comment: Do it in the Form's SizeChanged event.

Comment: And preventing the user to resize below a certain size is an acceptable option?

Comment: @Steve I would like to have the user be able to change the size as needed. This form can be used on a laptop screen or on a large monitor and sometimes needs to be smaller or larger than the original.

Comment: Have you tried using `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I was able to complete using your suggestion. There was still the possibility of controls "crawling" off the screen as the scroll bar would cause them to move left or up when the controls were not anchored. This was fixed with a few if statements. There was a similar issue when maximizing then restoring, same fix for that helped. Thanks!